# how to grant all user using mysql server

Tags: mysql, vb.net-2010

i been reading for i think 5 hours about this mysql server since i'm new to it.
[image]
[image]

even in my own machine i can't login. i know this is not new to you. can you please enlighten me here? but when i change it to localhost i connect. as you can see i change the hostname. i want that all in my network to connect in mysql. i am not sure if i'm in the right way.
here is my connection in the vs 2010;

```
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection("server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;userid=root;password=root;database=dbname")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE USER 'user1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname . * TO 'user1';

Flush privileges;
```

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/26912/mysql-hostname-wildcard

> The WITH GRANT OPTION clause gives the user the ability to give to
>   other users any privileges the user has at the specified privilege
>   level

.

Comment: is user1 = root im my statemat above? or do i have to create a new user?

Comment: it will not change my code? like userid=root or user1?

Comment: You preferably need each user to be identified but **at least** have end users not logging in as root

Comment: So end users could say login all as user1

Comment: But absolutely do what Rahul said for root guy

Comment: The link I provided suggests not specifying the host part

Comment: And don't give non-root guys access to db's they should not be in

Comment: it says "can't find any matching row in the user table"? i used this GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON s3printdb . * TO 's3print';

Comment: U don't have a s3print user yet? What was your actual create user call?

Comment: Ok hold on looking it up

Comment: i'm in i think i am going to jump right now i have been reading for 5 hours i'm glad i ask here. here is my new line > grant all privileges on dbname.* TO s3print@'%' identified by 'pass'.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply it save me now its working on my two machine.

Comment: Grant all on dbname.* to s4print@'%' identified by 'pass123'

Answer (score 1):

Change your `GRANT` command like below. See [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) for more information.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO  root@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```